# window.open not working in IE8 but working properly in FF3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

i have requirement to open a new window on click of some link my code is

```
var url = data['featureHelpUrl'];
        var win = window.open(url, "_blank",
                "height=750,width=600,scrollbars=yes");
        win.focus();
```

this code is opening window in FF but not opening in IE

Comment: Probably due to the pop-up blocker. You should be getting the yellow bar in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

popup blocker! the popup blocker works differently in the 2 browsers from what i remember -- if you trigger this code as a result of an onclick event should work though, otherwise you will be subject to popup blocking.